# Ubuntu Software Center (12.04) Error

Tags: 12.04, software-center, downloads

Almost every time I try to download from Ubuntu Software Center it claims that files are all 380.5mb on the first attempt to download. Even when downloading programs like Chromium which is really 24.1 mb. So I have to cancel the download and on the second try it gets it right. Can someone explain how to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu Software Center - Install errors**

I have not really an answer, but try to start Ubuntu Software Center **over the Terminal** and look what it shows up, when you install some software.

Or try to install the same software via **sudo apt-get install** xxxxx. Maybe there s an Error Message that could explain what s going on there.

Kind regards